# express-fileupload image upload not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, file-upload

So i am trying to allow users to upload a profile image for there profile and i got the form kinda how i want it for now but i keep running into an error saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'profilePicUpload' of undefined`

even though i am almost certain that all of my code is fine here is the routes.js

```
    // app/routes.js
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var dbconfig = require('../config/database');
    var connection = mysql.createConnection(dbconfig.connection);
    const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

    module.exports = function(app, passport) {

        app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
            req.logout();
            res.redirect('/');
        });
        // =====================================
        // HOME PAGE (with login links) ========
        // =====================================
        app.get('/', function(req, res) {
            res.render('login.ejs', { message: req.flash('loginMessage') }); // load the index.ejs file
        });

        // =====================================
        // LOGIN ===============================
        // =====================================
        // show the login form
        app.get('/login', function(req, res) {

            // render the page and pass in any flash data if it exists
            res.render('login.ejs', { message: req.flash('loginMessage') });
        });


        app.use(fileUpload());

       app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
         console.log(req.files.profilePicUpload);
       });



        passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
            done(null, user.id);
        });


        passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
            User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
                done(err, user);
            });
        });
        // process the login form
        app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
                successRedirect: '/mainchat', // redirect to the secure profile section
                failureRedirect: '/login', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
                failureFlash: true // allow flash messages
            }),
            function(req, res) {
                console.log("hello");

                if (req.body.remember) {
                    req.session.cookie.maxAge = 1000 * 60 * 3;
                } else {
                    req.session.cookie.expires = false;
                }
                res.redirect('/');
            });

        // =====================================
        // SIGNUP ==============================
        // =====================================
        // show the signup form
        app.get('/signup', function(req, res) {
            // render the page and pass in any flash data if it exists
            res.render('signup.ejs', { message: req.flash('signupMessage') });
        });

        // process the signup form
        app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
            successRedirect: '/mainchat', // redirect to the secure profile section
            failureRedirect: '/signup', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
            failureFlash: true // allow flash messages
        }));

        // =====================================
        // PROFILE SECTION =========================
        // =====================================
        // we will want this protected so you have to be logged in to visit
        // we will use route middleware to verify this (the isLoggedIn function)
        app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
            var aboutUser = connection.query("SELECT about FROM users WHERE username = ?", req.user, function(err, rows) {
                res.render('profile.ejs', {
                    user: req.user,
                    about: rows
                });
            });
        });

        app.get('/mainchat', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
            var username = req.user.displayName;
            res.render('mainchat.ejs', username);
            console.log(req.user.displayName)
        });
        // =====================================
        // LOGOUT ============================= rows.forEach(function(row) {=
        // =====================================
        app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
            req.logout();
            res.redirect('/');
        });



    };

    // route middleware to make sure
    function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

        // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on
        if (req.isAuthenticated())
            return next();

        // if they aren't redirect them to the home page
        res.redirect('/');
    }
```

and here is my upload form

```
            <form id="form" action="/upload" method="POST">
                <div class="fileUpload" id="profile-picture-upload">

                    <input name="profilePictureToUpload" type="file" id="profile-picture-upload" class="upload" />
                </div>
                <input type="submit" name="profilePicUpload" id="upload-profilePic-button"></input>
            </form>
```

when i press enter it just shows that error i said above ? can someone please help me

Answer (score 1):

Print out the content of req.files.  ie `console.log(req.files);`
should you be using `req.files.profilePictureToUpload` instead?  As opposed to `req.files.profilePicUpload`;

If you don't see the property, then it's likely an issue with the file contents not getting appended onto the request object properly.

Also, you don't need to globally apply the file upload to every single route you're using.  just use it for whichever endpoint actually uploads:

```
   app.post('/upload', fileUpload(), function(req, res) {
     console.log(req.files.profilePicUpload);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use express-fileupload in app.js as a middle ware

```
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const app = express()
app.use(fileUpload());
```

then you can see req.files anywhare in routes or in app